# Adding Current time in datatables Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I'm trying to add the time to my index page in the datatable but after migration the only time that shows up in the table on my index page is the time that the migration took place. I've tried many different ways but can't seem to find a way to display the time when a new form has been created in the application I'm working on. I am new to Ruby on Rails so a detailed explanation would be helpful.

```
class AddTimeToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change  
    add_column :articles, :time, :string, default: Time.now.strftime('%m-%e-%y %H:%M')
  end
end
```

Comment: All database objects have a `created_at` time field already. If you're just trying to get a time for when the object was created I would suggest you use that.

Comment: They don't all have a created_at field. However the standard Rails migrations do create that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Rails migrations will include a `timestamp` helper which creates `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. Those are special fields that Rails will use and update as needed.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

> The timestamps macro adds two columns, created_at and updated_at.
>   These special columns are automatically managed by Active Record if
>   they exist.

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, if you don't have those fields in your table, you can add them via a migration too.

```
class AddTimestampsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :created_at, :datetime
    add_column :products, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use database function like now():

```
default: 'now()'
```

Or use default rails column created_at

Answer (score 0):

Column should be `datetime`, just pass `null: false` and Rails add time without you:

```
class AddTimeToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change  
    add_column :articles, :time, :datetime, null: false
  end
end

=> a = Article.create(name: 'Foobar')
=> a.time
# Mon, 07 Jul 2014 15:08:37 UTC +00:00
```